# Returning record(s) after store pushPayload call

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Is there a better way to return the record(s) after `DS.Store#pushPayload` is called? This is what I'm doing...

```
var payload = { id: 1, title: "Example" }
store.pushPayload('post', payload);
return store.getById('post', payload.id);
```

But, with regular `DS.Store#push` you get the inserted record returned. The only difference between the two, from what I can tell, is that `DS.Store#pushPayload` serializes the payload data with the correct serializers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DS.Store#pushPayload` is able to take an *array* of items, not just one, and may contain side-loaded data. It processes a full payload and expects root keys in the payload:

```
{
  "posts": [{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "title",
    "comments": [1]
  }],
  "comments": [
    //.. and so on ...
  ]
}
```

`DS.Store#push` expects a single record which has been normalized and contains no side loaded data (notice there is no root key):

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "title",
  "comments": [1]
}
```

For this reason, it makes sense for `push` to return the record, but for `pushPayload` to return nothing.

When you use `pushPayload`, a second lookup of `store.find('post', 1)` (or `store.getById('post', 1)`) is the way to go, I don't believe there is a *better* way.

Comment: Yeah, that's kind of what I thought while looking around the ember-data code. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As of [this PR](https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/4110) `pushPayload` can now return an array of all the records pushed into the store, once the `'ds-pushpayload-return'` [feature flag](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.3.0/configuring-ember/feature-flags/) has been enabled.

At the moment, this feature isn't available in a standard or beta release-- you'll have to use

```
"ember-data": "emberjs/data#master",
```

(i.e. Canary) in your `package.json` in order to access it. I'm not sure when the feature will be generally available.